# Brute Force algorithm for multidimensional knapsack

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, brute-force, knapsack-problem

I'm looking for a brute force algorithm for the multidimensional knapsack problem with 4 knapsacks.

I have done some research on here and other websites but couldn't find anything helpful so far. Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean multiple knapsack problem where [we have n items and m knapsacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems)?

The answers to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77026/multiple-knapsack-using-dynamic-programming) or [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81186/multi-knapsack-problem-variation) similar questions on stackexchange can be helpful.

*Note: I don't have enough points to write a comment.*